# JBoss6 Classloading logging

Tags: logging, jboss, classloader, jboss6.x

We are having some class loading issues when deploying an application to JBoss AS 6.0.0 Final.  Is there any logging that can be enabled within JBoss to see when classes are being loaded and by which classloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can try to monitor classes in package `org.jboss.classloader`. Just add such lines to your `jboss-logging.xml` file (you can find that file in `deploy` directory):

```
   <periodic-rotating-file-handler
         file-name="${jboss.server.log.dir}/cl.log"
         name="CL"
         autoflush="true"
         append="true"
         suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd"> 

      <error-manager>
         <only-once/>
      </error-manager>

      <formatter>
         <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
      </formatter>
   </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

   <logger category="org.jboss.classloader">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
      <handlers>
         <handler-ref name="CL"/>
      </handlers>
   </logger>
```

After that you can find some information about class loading in the `log/cl.log` file.

More info can be found in that article: [EnableClassloaderLogging](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EnableClassloaderLogging)

Answer (score 4):

Use JVM `-verbose:class` option. For JBoss You add the following line to your `run.sh`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -verbose:class
```

...and on Windows (`run.bat`):

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -verbose:class"
```